# Class type for stack allocation. Why the address for both ID instances are the same?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack-allocation

```
class ID
{
public:
    ID(const std::string& name) :
        name_(name) {}

    // explicit copy constructor as my first solution but gave me same address
    ID(const ID& other)
    { name_ = other.getName(); } 

    std::string getName() const
    { return name_; }

private:
    std::string name_;
};

ID createID(const std::string& name)
{
    ID id(name); // new stack allocation for id
    std::cout << "ID addr: " << &id << "\n";
    return id;
}

int main()
{
    ID my_id = createID("John"); // new stack allocation for my_id
    std::cout << "my_id addr: " << &my_id << "\n";
    std::cout << my_id.getName() << std::endl;
}
```

Platform: Ubuntu terminal (Windows' Ubuntu Subsystem)

Compilation: g++ file.cpp

Output: "Same address between IDs"

Shouldn't the output provided different stack address?

I tried replicating this with primitive integer (instead of ID class type) and it outputs different address for different instances.

```
int func(int i)
{
        int j = i;
        std::cout << "i addr: " << &i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "j addr: " << &j << std::endl;
        return i;
}

int main()
{
        int x = 10;

        std::cout << "X addr: " << &x << std::endl;
        int y = func(x);
        std::cout << "Y addr: " << &y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please show the complete example you are running. Nowhere in your code do I see "Same address between IDs".

Comment: The class starts at the beginning of first variable. If it is an inherited class it starts with the first variable of the partent class. If it has virtual functions then it starts with address of virtual table. So the first variable address is the same as the address of the class. If there are more variables in the class, each new variable is placed after previous one.

Comment: That's called *Named Return Value Optimization* or *NRVO*. It seems we only have duplicate that explains both RVO and copy ellison - [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
ID createID(const std::string& name)
{
    ID id(name); // new stack allocation for id
    std::cout << "ID addr: " << &id << "\n";
    return id;
}
```

for the call:

```
ID my_id = createID("John"); // new stack allocation for my_id
```

it appears the compiler is doing [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (named return value optimization). So there is no actual copy of `id` in the function to the variable `my_id`, and no separate allocation.

Instead this copy is elided, and you see the same address. So the comment `// new stack allocation for my_id` is actually incorrect.

Note that NRVO is not guaranteed to happen, so you shouldn't rely on this behavior. The compiler *could* make a copy, resulting in different addresses. In fact this is what happens in the example where `func` returns an `int`. Since this is a cheap to copy type, the compiler actually makes a copy, and you see different addresses.